# Create an android app to view pages of an existing PHP/MySQL website

Tags: php, android, web, view

I'm looking to create an android that will simply display the pages of my existing website.

However, my website is based on PHP and MYSQL for signing in/up and adding information to the database using forms.

The available solutions I found are working with static HTML websites and not dynamic ones. Is there any solution available to view dynamic websites based on PHP from an android app?

Comment: Have you tried using webview?

Answer (score 1):

php is a serverside language which is pretty much useless for clientside development, something that may be word investing time in for you is learning angular, you need to know html & javascript. AngularJS has free tutorials on 3WS and has a low learning curve.